# standard deviation of the reciprocal of a ratio

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, standard-deviation, ratio

I have a sample mean ratio of 16 (as in, 16 male to 1 female) and a standard error of 2 (sample size is 10, normal distribution).

I want to find the mean and standard deviation (not error this time) of the ratio of female to male. I first find the reciprocal of 16 to calculate the mean ratio, 1/16. I know that standard deviation = standard error*sqrt(n).

How do I plug in my standard error of the ratio into this equation? (1/2)*sqrt(10) does not seem correct.

Comment: How do you get a ratio of 16-1 with a sample size of 10?

Comment: One asymmetric hermaphrodite who is 60% female? Or maybe the intent was 6 female in a sample of 100?

Answer (score 1):

The standard error formula you mention relies on a [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Central_limit_theorem), which is not necessarily appropriate unless your sample size is large enough.

Your data would be better described using the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), whose parameters would be $p$ and $N$, where
$$p=\frac{M}{N} \text{ , } N=M+F$$
with $M=$ # male, and $F=$ # female.

Within this framework, your ratio would be
$$\frac{M}{F}=\frac{p}{1-p}$$
the [odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) of "male", where $p$ is the fraction of males.

Several approaches to estimating confidence intervals for $p$ are summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Confidence_intervals), and described in more detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval).